# command print no results with (interactive "r")

Tags: functions, interactive, echo-area, print

Consider this test function (tested in emacs -q):

```
  (defun foo (start end)
   "for testing purposes"
   (interactive "r")
   (when (region-active-p)
     (cons start end)))
```

Calling `M-x foo` gives no results printed in the minibuffer, even when a region is active.
If I evaluate `M-: (call-interactively #'foo)` the cons is printed in the minibuffer.

I'd be happy to know why nothing is printed with `M-x foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the echoing of the return value by `M-:` with the action of `M-x`.

`M-:` expressly evaluates a sexp *and* prints the resulting value. `M-x` invokes a command.

Your command does not, itself, print or echo or otherwise display its return value.

If you want your command to echo the value, then use function `message`:

```lisp
(when (region-active-p)
  (let ((val (cons start end)))
    (message "Result: %S" val)
    val))
```

Comment: This does not exactly answer my question. I thought in the evaluation loop (read (eval (print))) the evaluation stream was displayed in the mini-buffer. I had never observed it to be otherwise until now.

Comment: I think it does answer your question. What you thought is wrong *"the evaluation stream [is] displayed in the mini-buffer"*. Display in the echo area is due to explicit calls to functions such as `message`.